# Adding annotation to JAXB xml

Tags: java, json, jaxb

I want add an annotation to the XML file provided to JAXB.

We have a requirement where I will create the objects with same attribute names and datatypes but will have different JSON keys for them.

The key names in JSON will differ on the basis of annotation provided. These annotations are GSON annotations for example: @SerializedName("key name of JSON you would like").

I tried to get some inputs from the question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563351/how-to-dynamically-generate-and-retrieve-json-in-java-code)

But could not really get any solution.

Anyone has any suggestion?

I will add some XML schema to explain.

```
<xsd:complexType name="RouteType">
 <xsd:attribute name="Pos" type="xsd:int" use="optional" default="1"/>
 <xsd:attribute name="Dir" type="DirType" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Now in above schema can I add an annotation to attribute Pos?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say add annotation to JAXB XML?

Comment: I think I will modify the question a bit so that it is easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're asking how to have the JAXB compiler automatically annotate the generated classes.  There's a JAXB plugin for adding annotations: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin

You can hook it into the `generate-sources` phase of a Maven build like so:

```
<build>
    <!-- snip -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>path/to/your/schema.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <bindingIncludes>
                            <include>path/to/your/custom-bindings.xjb</include> <!-- if you choose to use a custom bindings file instead of inline annotations in the xsd -->
                        </bindingIncludes>
                        <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <episode>false</episode>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                        </args>
                        <plugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                                <version>0.6.4</version>
                            </plugin>
                        </plugins>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If the above plugin doesn't do exactly what you want (which I think it should, it looks pretty flexible), it shouldn't be too difficult to roll your own modification (I have done this before for adding copy constructors to generated classes).