# Getting dynamic property names with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to create json where the objects are all structured similarly, but can contain different object names, i.e.:

```
    "obj1":{
         "field1":1,
         "field2":2
     }
    "obj2":{
         "field1":4,
         "field2":5
     }
    "obj3":{
         "field1":7,
         "field2":8
     }
```

How can I use jackson to create dynanic field names? this would be done during run time depending on input taken

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jackson dynamic property names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134231/jackson-dynamic-property-names)

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly refer to this answer: [Jackson dynamic property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134231/jackson-dynamic-property-names).

Basically you can use a custom [JsonSerializer](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JsonSerializer).

```
  @JsonProperty("p")
  @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
  private Object data;

  // ...

public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
  public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    jgen.writeStartObject();
    jgen.writeObjectField(value.getClass().getName(), value);
    jgen.writeEndObject();
  }
}
```