# Stackoverflow exception when trying to use custom JsonSerializer (Jackson)

Tags: java, json, jackson, wildfly

I am trying to serialize the object to JSON using Jackson, so that the field name is based on a type of field.

I have the same problem as the OP in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134231/jackson-dynamic-property-names) thread:

However, it's not working.

I am using Wildfly 10.1 Final

I did the following:

- added `resteasy-jackson2` dependency as provided to `pom.xml`.
- Created *CustomSerializer* class as specified in the post I linked.

CustomSerializer class:

```
public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
  public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    jgen.writeStartObject();
    jgen.writeObjectField(value.getClass().getSimpleName(), value);
    jgen.writeEndObject();
  }
}
```

- Added `@JsonProperty("data")` annotation to the object field, so my Response class now looks like this:

  ```
  public class ResponseWithReturnValue extends Response {
      @JsonProperty("data")
      private Object object;

      public ResponseWithReturnValue (int code, String msg) {
          super(code, msg);
      }

      public Object getObject() {
          return object;
      }

      public void setObject(Object object) {
          this.object = object;
      }
  }
  ```

When I test it I get the following json object:

```
{"code":0,"message":"Success","data":"test"}
```

So, the *@JsonProperty* annotation is working but the custom JsonSerializer isn't.

Now, I tried what was suggested in [this](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization) blog, and added `@JsonSerialize(using=CustomSerializer.class)` annotation on my *ResponseWithReturnValue* class.

However, now I get this StackOverflow :) exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethodInfo(Class.java:1072)
at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass(Class.java:1272)
at java.lang.Class.getSimpleBinaryName(Class.java:1443)
at java.lang.Class.getSimpleName(Class.java:1309)
at rs.netset.authority.web.facade.utils.CustomSerializer.serialize(CustomSerializer.java:13)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2383)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeObject(GeneratorBase.java:324)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.writeObjectField(JsonGenerator.java:1415)
at rs.netset.authority.web.facade.utils.CustomSerializer.serialize(CustomSerializer.java:13)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2383)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeObject(GeneratorBase.java:324)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.writeObjectField(JsonGenerator.java:1415)
at rs.netset.authority.web.facade.utils.CustomSerializer.serialize(CustomSerializer.java:13)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2383)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeObject(GeneratorBase.java:324)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.writeObjectField(JsonGenerator.java:1415)
at rs.netset.authority.web.facade.utils.CustomSerializer.serialize(CustomSerializer.java:13)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2383)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeObject(GeneratorBase.java:324)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.writeObjectField(JsonGenerator.java:1415)
at rs.netset.authority.web.facade.utils.CustomSerializer.serialize(CustomSerializer.java:13)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2383)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeObject(GeneratorBase.java:324)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.writeObjectField(JsonGenerator.java:1415)
at rs.netset.authority.web.facade.utils.CustomSerializer.serialize(CustomSerializer.java:13)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2383)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeObject(GeneratorBase.java:324)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.writeObjectField(JsonGenerator.java:1415)
at rs.netset.authority.web.facade.utils.CustomSerializer.serialize(CustomSerializer.java:13)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2383)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeObject(GeneratorBase.java:324)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.writeObjectField(JsonGenerator.java:1415)
at rs.netset.authority.web.facade.utils.CustomSerializer.serialize(CustomSerializer.java:13)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2383)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeObject(GeneratorBase.java:324)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.writeObjectField(JsonGenerator.java:1415)
at rs.netset.authority.web.facade.utils.CustomSerializer.serialize(CustomSerializer.java:13)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2383)
```

I wasn't able to post full stacktrace because it's way too long.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, serialize, serializeValue, writeValue, writeObject and writeObjectField are called indefinitely, so that's what's causing StackOverflowException, but I'm not sure what's the cause.

Comment: Stack overflow is often caused by infinite recursion.  This is the cause of your problem.

Comment: When reviewing a stack trace to debug a recursion issue, include the top 10 - 15 lines, identify the repeating parts, then include the bottom 10 - 15 lines.

Comment: `jgen.writeObjectField(value.getClass().getSimpleName(), value);` looks wrong.  The first parameter is fieldname, not class name.

Answer (score 2):

You have created an infinite recursion by always delegating to the same (your custom) serializer. The line `jgen.writeObjectField(value.getClass().getSimpleName(), value);` calls your custom serializer in order to serialize `Object`, which again calls `jgen.writeObjectField(...)` and so on.

You can delegate to another serializer or actually serialize the object:

```
jgen.writeObjectFieldStart("objectFieldName");
jgen.writeStringField("someValue", value.getSomeValue());
//...
jgen.writeEndObject();
```