# Adding a dynamic json property as java pojo for jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I need to create a Json payload like this from Java pojo :

```
{ "update" : {
    "labels" : [{"add" : "A label"} ]
    }
 }
```

so I created a Java pojo like this :

```
@JsonRootName(value = "update")
public class AddLabel{
  @JsonProperty("labels")
  public List<Label> labels; 
  public AddLabel(String labelName){
     this.labels = new ArrayList<>(); 
     this.labels.add(new Label(labelName); 
  }
  public static class Label{
    public String add; 
    public Label(String labelName){
       this.add = labelName; 
    }
  }
}
```

I like to have the "add" property in Label class as dynamic, so that it can also take values such as "remove", "set" . Is there a way to do this other than creating another POJO's for each of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [JsonAnyGetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnyGetter.html) annotation which allows to create dynamic `key-value` pairs. Below example shows how we can generate 3 different keys for the same `Label` class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AddLabel label = new AddLabel("A label");
        label.getLabels().add(AddLabel.Label.remove("Remove"));
        label.getLabels().add(AddLabel.Label.set("Set"));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(label));
    }
}

@JsonRootName(value = "update")
class AddLabel {

    @JsonProperty("labels")
    private List<Label> labels;

    public AddLabel(String labelName) {
        this.labels = new ArrayList<>();
        this.labels.add(Label.add(labelName));
    }

    public List<Label> getLabels() {
        return labels;
    }

    public static class Label {

        private final String key;
        private final String value;

        private Label(String key, String value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public static Label add(String value) {
            return new Label("add", value);
        }

        public static Label remove(String value) {
            return new Label("remove", value);
        }

        public static Label set(String value) {
            return new Label("set", value);
        }

        @JsonAnyGetter
        public Map<String, String> getDynamic() {
            return Collections.singletonMap(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "labels" : [ {
    "add" : "A label"
  }, {
    "remove" : "Remove"
  }, {
    "set" : "Set"
  } ]
}
```

See also:

- [Jackson @JsonAnyGetter and @JsonAnySetter Example](https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-jsonanygetter-and-jsonanysetter-example)
- [Jackson Annotation Examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)
- [How to use dynamic property names for a Json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55684724/how-to-use-dynamic-property-names-for-a-json-object/55687330#55687330)

Answer (score 1):

Your specification isn't clear, you would have many of the same action (add, remove, etc) or just one at most?

**First Option**
In case you have at most single instance of the same action, you can replace the array with regular object:

```
{ "update" : {
    "labels" : {
       "add" : "A label",
       "remove" : "B label"
      }
    }
 }
```

and then change your labels to a `Map<String, String>` instead of `List<Label>`

**Second Option**
In case you have many instances of the same action, you can change the design of label to contain two fields, `value` and `action`

```
{ "update" : {
    "labels" : [{"action": "add", "value" : "A label"} ]
    }
 }
```

And update `Label` accordingly:

```java
  public static class Label{
    public String action;
    public String value 
    public Label(String action, String value){
       this.action = action;
       this.value = value; 
    }
  }
```

You can also change `action` to `enum` which define all your possible actions

**Third Option**
If you really need to stick to your json design, you don't have a lot of options to define static typing class for a dynamic json. maybe it's possible to hack this somehow using jackons's polymorphism. But you can always just use the json objects and leave the labels as `List<JsonObject>`