# Is there a way for omitting certain fields from matching array elements of JSON array of content of JSON response based on a criteria in spring boot

Tags: json, serialization, filter, jackson

but it should retain the fields in other array elements which did not match the criteria.
I have json response like below

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "someId": 1498,
            "someKey": {
                "anotherKey": "Not Specified",
                "keyOne": "",
                "keyTwo": null,
                "keyThree": null
            },
            "date": "2009-09-11",
            "time": "17:14",
            "location": "Not Specified"
        },
        {
            "someId": 1498,
            "someKey": {
                "anotherKey": "criteria",
                "keyOne": "some data",
                "keyTwo": "some data for key two",
                "keyThree": "some data for key three"
            },
            "date": "2009-09-12",
            "time": "17:15",
            "location": "Not Specified"
        },...
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true,
            "empty": true
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "unpaged": false,
        "paged": true
    },
    "totalElements": 10630,
    "totalPages": 1063,
    "last": false,
    "size": 10,
    "number": 0,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true,
        "empty": true
    },
    "first": true,
    "numberOfElements": 10,
    "empty": false
}
```

when "anotherKey" value is "criteria", the "keyOne","keyTwo","keyThree" should be omitted, else it should be retained. any solution to this? thanks in advance

Comment: `someKey` looks like an object which on `Java` side probably is represented by a `POJO` class. Use `@JsonAnyGetter` annotation and implement method which will return map with required set of key-value pairs. See also: [Adding a dynamic json property as java pojo for jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245719/adding-a-dynamic-json-property-as-java-pojo-for-jackson/56247021#56247021)

Comment: The response is from an Entity Class which is wrapped by `PageImpl`. so it possible to implement `@JsonAnyGetter`  at entity level or should I use a TO?

Comment: What do you mean by `TO`? You can use `@JsonAnyGetter` annotation on `Entity` level.

Comment: Transfer Object

Comment: It depends from you, you can create a new `TO` or use `Entity`. These two options have it's own pros and cons.