# How can I serialize the key values pairs of a map as top level keys in the serialised JSON?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Having the class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String id;
    private Map<String, Object> properties;
    ...
}
```

and using Jackson, can I tell Jackson (via annotation) to serialize the key values in the `properties` map to top level key values in the `MyClass` serialization?

For example, if `properties` contains a couple of key-values: `fruit - apple`, `color - red` I would like to generate a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "if": "...",
    "fruit": "apple",
    "color": "red"
}
```

instead of:

```
{
    "if": "...",
    "properties": {
        "fruit": "apple",
        "color": "red"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to annotate getter method with `@JsonAnyGetter` annotation. Take a look on similar questions: [Adding a dynamic json property as java pojo for jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245719/adding-a-dynamic-json-property-as-java-pojo-for-jackson/56247021#56247021), [How to use dynamic property names for a Json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55684724/how-to-use-dynamic-property-names-for-a-json-object/55687330#55687330)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I serialize the key values pairs of a map as top level keys in
> the serialised JSON?

A possible way to solve your issue is create a custom serializer for your `MyClass` class and annotate your class with the [`JsonSerialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) annotation:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MyClassSerializer.class)
public class MyClass {
    private String id;
    private Map<String, Object> properties;
}
```

In the custom serializer you can iterate over the `properties` map and build the representation of your object like below:

```
public class MyClassSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(MyClass t, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException {
        jg.writeStartObject();
        jg.writeStringField("id", t.getId());
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : t.getProperties().entrySet()) {
            jg.writeObjectField(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        jg.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

An example using your data :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        Map<String, Object> properties = Map.of(
                "fruit", "apple",
                "color", "red"
        );
        mc.setId("myid");
        mc.setProperties(properties);
        System.out.println(mc);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //it will print {"id":"myid","color":"red","fruit":"apple"}
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(mc));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The annotation [@JsonUnwrapped](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Apparently Map objects are not reacting at `@JsonUnwrapped` (only POJO objects do)  ...