# How to make Jackson ignore the serialization of field b if field a is false when serializing

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

When using jackson serialization, field b is ignored when field a is false

```
public class MyClass {
    private boolean a;
    private int b;
}
```

I haven't found a solution yet，Trying to use @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = AlarmConfig.TrueFilter.class) only works for single field

Comment: This is just a bad idea. Instead, set `b` to `null` and have Jackson ignore null values instead. Added bonus: You probably won't even need `a` at all any more (just check `b != null`)

Comment: You can try to use `@JsonAnyGetter` annotation and implement a method which checks any conditions and return as many different fields as you want. Take a look on this example [Jackson diffrent name base of other field value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75044947/51591)

Answer (score 0):

You may create your own serializer, something like:

```java
public class MyClassSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(MyClass value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeBooleanField("a", value.isA());
        if (value.isA()) {
            gen.writeNumberField("b", value.getB());
        }
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```java
@JsonSerialize(using = MyClassSerializer.class)
public class MyClass { ... }
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it more general?