# JSON Jackson deserialization multiple keys into same field

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to convert JSON into POJO. 
I have worked with Jackson to convert standard JSON file.
In this particular case, I would like to overwrite the key value to "default" class/variable. In this case, there are multiple key value to be replaced (ie. hundreds, and the key values to be replaced are unknown).

Is this possible? I thought of storing it into Map, then iterate and store each into POJO, but wondering if there is different option, since I am not that familiar with storing JSON to Map.

Example of the JSON to be processed:

```
"People" : {
    "person1" : { 
      "name" : "john doe",
      "address" : "123 main st",
      "email" : "john@doe.com"
    },
    "person2" : { 
      "name" : "bob cat",
      "address" : "234 dog st",
      "email" : "bob@cat.com"
    },
    "person3" : { 
      "name" : "foo bar",
      "address" : "111  1st ave",
      "email" : "foo@bar.com"
    },
    "person8" : { 
      "name" : "james bono",
      "address" : "999 alaska st",
      "email" : "james@bono.com"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to generate the class in the following structure? The main issue is there are hundreds of value to be replaced and assuming they are unknown, I can't use this approach.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class People { 

  @JsonAlias({"person1", "person2"})
  private List<Details> person; // --> this should be the default replacing person1, person2, and so on 

  private class Details { 
    String name;
    String address;
    String email;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [JsonAnySetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnySetter.html) annotation for all properties `personXYZ`. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(jsonFile, People.class).getPersons());
    }
}

class People {

    private List<Details> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setPerson(String name, Details person) {
        this.persons.add(person);
    }

    public List<Details> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public static class Details {
        String name;
        String address;
        String email;

        // getters, setters, toString
    }
}
```

For your `JSON` above code prints:

```
[Details{name='john doe', address='123 main st', email='john@doe.com'}, Details{name='bob cat', address='234 dog st', email='bob@cat.com'}, Details{name='foo bar', address='111  1st ave', email='foo@bar.com'}, Details{name='james bono', address='999 alaska st', email='james@bono.com'}]
```

In case you use inner class remember to make it `public static` to make it visible to `Jackson` instantiation process.

See also:

- [How to use dynamic property names for a Json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55684724/how-to-use-dynamic-property-names-for-a-json-object)
- [Jackson Annotation Examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my two cents. I think this way looks nicer and is also easy to retrieve data. Jackson will do the deserialization without the need of any other tags or custom code, and it's all nice and sorted in a hashmap.

```
class People {

    private Map<String, Person> persons = new HashMap<>();

    // getter and setters
}
```

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    String address;
    String email;

    // getters and setters
}
```

}