# Deserialize multiple objects with same attributes but different class name using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

How can I deserialize multiple objects with same structure but different variable name using object mapper?

```
{ 
   "id":"A0D-29G3-03",
   "a":{ 
      "flag":"NORMAL",
      "date":"..."
   },
   "b":{ 
      "flag":"NORMAL",
      "date":"..."
   }
}
```

I'll have more objects than A and B. This is just an example. How can I deserialize multiple objects(using ObjectMapper) with same structure but different class name? Without creating one pojo for each class.....

Comment: This question is related to: [How can I deserialize a JSON to a Java class which has known mandatory fields, but can have several unknown fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081709/how-can-i-deserialize-a-json-to-a-java-class-which-has-known-mandatory-fields-b), [JSON Jackson deserialization multiple keys into same field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064917/json-jackson-deserialization-multiple-keys-into-same-field)

Answer (score 2):

> ... different class name

`a` and `b` are not different class names, are they? They are different fields which can share the same class. You can use one single class (`Abc` in the example) for fields `a`, `b`, etc.

Does this work for you?

```java
    @Setter
    @Getter
    @ToString
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class AbcWrapper {
        private String id;
        @JsonAnySetter
        Map<String, Abc> abc = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }

    @Setter
    @Getter
    @ToString
    public static class Abc {
        private String flag;
        private String date;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "{ " +
                "   \"id\":\"A0D-29G3-03\"," +
                "   \"a\":{ " +
                "      \"flag\":\"NORMAL\"," +
                "      \"date\":\"...\"" +
                "   }," +
                "   \"a1\":{ " +
                "      \"flag\":\"NORMAL\"," +
                "      \"date\":\"...\"" +
                "   }," +
                "   \"a2\":{ " +
                "      \"flag\":\"NORMAL\"," +
                "      \"date\":\"...\"" +
                "   }," +
                "   \"a3\":{ " +
                "      \"flag\":\"NORMAL\"," +
                "      \"date\":\"...\"" +
                "   }," +
                "   \"b\":{ " +
                "      \"flag\":\"NORMAL\"," +
                "      \"date\":\"...\"" +
                "   }" +
                "}";


        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final AbcWrapper abcWrapper = mapper.readValue(json.getBytes(), AbcWrapper.class);
        System.out.println(abcWrapper);
    }
```

I used lombok annotations `@Setter`, `@Getter`, `@ToString` in the example. You can replace them with setters/getters if you don't want to use lombok.

Comment: so what do you do if you have hundreds of `a`'s and `b`'s? the question is about that case

Comment: Yes you are correct. It's not different class names, it's different variable names. It's like Vault23 commented. What if I've many `a`'s and `b`'s? I want it to be dynamic

Comment: You can look at ```@JsonAnySetter```. I've modified the example in the answer.

Comment: @ПетрАлександров yes, your answer is correct, `@JsonAnySetter` is a good way to use here.