# Deserialize multiple json keys to one field with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am calling a REST api that returns a json response like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "code": {
      "code1": {
        "name": "some-name",
        "value": "0.25"
      },
      "code2": {
        "name": "some-name2",
        "value": "0.88"
      },
      "code3": {
        "name": "some-name3",
        "value": "0.00"
      },
      "code4": {
        "name": "some-name4",
        "value": "-0.11"
      },
      "code5": {
        "name": "some-name5",
        "value": "0.99"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I modeled this to the following POJO (for clarity, I omit `Data` class):

```
@Data
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Code {
    @JsonAlias({"code1", "code2", "code3", "code4", "code5"})
    private final CustomCode customCode;
}
```

This works fine if there is only one object below "code". In the example above, with code1 to code5 CustomCode will only have one of the "codeX" objects - where X is 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.

I know I could use a Map but I would like to avoid using a map if possible. What I look forward to find is something like:

```
@Data
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Code {
    @JsonAlias({"code1", "code2", "code3", "code4", "code5"})
    private final List<CustomCode> customCodeList;
}
```

Where `customCodeList` will hold each code1 to code5 pojos.
So my question is: does Jackson offer some annotation/configuration that allows us to accomplish this?

Comment: No annotation for that is seems. A [custom deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158345/custom-json-deserialization-with-jackson) could do.

Comment: Try to use [JsonAnySetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnySetter.html) annotation. See similar questions: [JSON Jackson deserialization multiple keys into same field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064917/json-jackson-deserialization-multiple-keys-into-same-field), [How can I deserialize a JSON to a Java class which has known mandatory fields, but can have several unknown fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081709/how-can-i-deserialize-a-json-to-a-java-class-which-has-known-mandatory-fields-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `@JsonAnySetter` like this:

```
public static class Code {

    private final List<CustomCode> customCodeList = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final Set<String> ALIASES = ImmutableSet.of("code1", "code2", "...");

    @JsonAnySetter
    private void set(String name, CustomCode value) {
        if (ALIASES.contains(name)) {
            customCodeList.add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

One downside of this approach is that if your `Code` object may arrive with unknown fields, you might need to change the second parameter of `set` to `Object` and parse it more carefully.