# Jackson in JSON Output: Rename Fields in Multiple Use Cases (without a single JsonProperty)

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is it possible to rename JSON output fields in an object an arbitrary number of times when outputting with Jackson?

I can use a one-time `JsonProperty` as shown here,

[How to map JSON field names to different object field names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741134/how-to-map-json-field-names-to-different-object-field-names)

But suppose I have a single class which is used in multiple outputs. In each output, I want to have the flexibility of defining which name(s) to change.

```
public class Study implements Serializable {

   // Can vary as "id" / "studyId" depending on call
   private int id;

   // Can vary as "description" / "studyDescription" / "studyDesc" depending on call
   private String description;
}
```

Or do I need to create new objects for each case?

Comment: Have you looked at Custom Deserializer? https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization. You could make the property name dynamic in a constructor of your Custom Deserializer.

Comment: Try to use `JsonAnyGetter` annotation. See: [How to use dynamic property names for a Json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55684724/how-to-use-dynamic-property-names-for-a-json-object), [Adding a dynamic json property as java pojo for jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245719/adding-a-dynamic-json-property-as-java-pojo-for-jackson), [Dynamic change of JsonProperty name using Jackson java library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845478/dynamic-change-of-jsonproperty-name-using-jackson-java-library)

Answer (score 0):

Do refer: https://www.baeldung.com/json-multiple-fields-single-java-field

It's as simple as using `@JsonAlias` in combination with `@JsonProperty` annotation as below:

```
public class Study implements Serializable {

   // Can vary as "id" / "studyId" depending on call
   @JsonProperty("id")
   @JsonAlias("studyId")
   private int id;

   // Can vary as "description" / "studyDescription" / "studyDesc" depending on call
   private String description;
}
```

PS: Using `@JsonProperty` twice didn't work :D