# Change naming of attributes in json without @JsonProperty

Tags: java, json

I have to convert my json from camelCase to kebab-case.

Example:

```
My Json:
{
    "disclaimerConfirmed" : true
}
```

And I need:

```
{
    "disclaimer-confirmed" : true
}
```

I cannot use @JsonProperty because it rename this atributes permanently. I am looking for something which will consume Json (can be as String) and returns modified json(as String).

Comment: you can also have a look on that (it shows you how to write custom JSON serializers, something that could work for your case), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134231/jackson-dynamic-property-names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson supports naming strategies so you could read the input String to map (with camelCase strategy) and then write the map back to a String (with [kebab-case](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.KebabCaseStrategy.html) which is natively supported );

Specific method you need to switch these conventions in ObjectMapper without annotations is:

```java
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.*);
```

Comment: This solution was the simplest, Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can have different serializers for different cases or you can create pojo with `@JsonProperty` and use those where-ever required.

For example,

```
class A {
 private String disclaimerConfirmed;

}

class AkebabCase {
   @JsonProperty("disclaimer-confirmed")
   private String disclaimerConfirmed;
}
```

So, if you want to serialize to kebab-case you can use converters to convert `A` to `AkebabCase` and then serialize.